# Restoring user mapping to login after SQL Server 2008 database restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server 2008 disaster recovery DB that gets restored on a nightly basis from our production server. Every time this happens, a specific user/login with read-only access to the DB breaks.

What is the best way to have the user/login either recreated, or the `db_datareader` user mapping to the database restored after the DB restore is complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused because SQL logins and SQL users use a SID as the actual identification, and the SID won't match since they're generated by each server individually.  Windows users and logins use the SID from the domain, so they work just fine.  Logins like `sa` and users like `dbo` use well-known SIDs that are fixed.

You're supposed to fix it with [ALTER USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
ALTER USER <UserName> WITH LOGIN <LoginName>;
```

But, IMX, most people still use [`sp_change_users_login`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378(v=sql.105).aspx), even though it's deprecated.  It's a bit more convenient because it doesn't require you to specify everything manually and you can remap multiple logins with one command.

```
--List orphaned users
EXEC sp_change_users_login @Action = 'Report';

--Auto remap users to logins that have the same name
EXEC sp_change_users_login @Action = 'Auto_Fix';

--Manual remap
EXEC sp_change_users_login @Action = 'Update_One', @UserNamePattern = <UserName>, @LoginName = <LoginName>;
```

Comment: If I do the above, will the user mapping/role membership (specifically db_datareader) for my database remain intact, or will that have to be reestablished as well?

Comment: @Aleks It should remain intact.  The model is that Logins are mapped to Server Roles in the master db.  Users are mapped to Database Roles in the user db.  Then Users are mapped to Logins by having matching SIDs.  That's the only mapping made between the Server security and Database security as far as accounts.  If your second server has the same Server Role and Login configuration, all you should need to do is run the `ALTER USER` command to remap them.