# Can't create SQL Server user

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to solve a problem with adding a user to a SQL Server database. Let's call this user `Login A`. Login A is a Windows AD account. I keep getting the following error.

> Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The login already has an account under a different user name

A bit of background: I originally created this database with `Login A` on one machine. I then restored it to another machine that was logged in with User B. Now when I try to add User A to the restored instance, I get that error.

From what I can tell, User A does not exist in the restored instance. I do not see it in either the `sys.server_principals` or `sys.database_principals` table. Furthermore, if I try to login as that user, I get a login failed message. Where would this user be hiding?

Comment: Check the Login

Comment: The login is probably still sitting at the server level and has lost it's mapping to the db login, or visa versa...i.e. that login is at one of the levels. Check both

Comment: How come I can't see the login anywhere?

Comment: You checked under your server > security > logins folder and server > databases > yourdb >  security > logins and you don't see the old username for that login?

Comment: @scsimon - Yes, the user is not listed there.

Comment: @Dave Login with "sa" then see if login "A" exist

Comment: Restores often seem to leave broken users with each server rolling its own.  Try checking out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29851274/restoring-user-mapping-to-login-after-sql-server-2008-database-restore

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bc14e5f5-abe4-4623-b612-1f79bcd4395f/database-owners-not-found-in-syslogins-or-sysserverprincipals?forum=sqlsecurity

Comment: Try this...`EXEC xp_logininfo 'DOMAIN\user_a', 'all'`

Comment: @scsimon the xp_logininfo did not return anything, however  `select suser_sname(sid), sid from sys.database_principals where name = 'dbo'` returns `User A`

Comment: Check this - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35225/the-login-already-has-an-account-under-a-different-user-name.
I guess this should answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `User A` is orphaned. Below is a script that will detect orphaned users and create a drop script in order to properly delete them. You should then be able to recreate `User A` correctly.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(2000)
DECLARE @name nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @database_id int

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT name FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE name like '%#orphan_users%')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #orphan_users
        (
        database_name nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
        [user_name] nvarchar(128) NOT NULL,
        drop_command_text nvarchar(200) NOT NULL
        )
END

CREATE TABLE #databases 
(
    database_id int NOT NULL
    , database_name nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
    , processed bit NOT NULL
)

INSERT
    #databases 
    ( database_id
    , database_name
    , processed )
SELECT 
    database_id
    , name
    , 0 
FROM 
    master.sys.databases 
WHERE 
    name NOT IN 
    ('master'
    , 'tempdb'
    , 'msdb'
    , 'distribution'
    , 'model')

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(processed) FROM #databases WHERE processed = 0) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1
        @name = database_name,
        @database_id = database_id
    FROM #databases
    WHERE processed = 0
    ORDER BY database_id

    SELECT @SQL =

'USE [' + @name + '];
INSERT INTO #orphan_users (database_name, user_name, drop_command_text)
SELECT 
    DB_NAME()
    , u.name
    , ' + '''' 
    + 'USE [' + @name + ']; ' 
    + 'DROP USER [' 
    + '''' + ' + u.name 
    + ' + '''' + '] ' 
    + '''' + '
FROM
    master..syslogins l
RIGHT JOIN 
    sysusers u 
ON l.sid = u.sid
WHERE   
    l.sid IS NULL
AND issqlrole <> 1
AND isapprole <> 1
AND ( u.name <> ' + '''' + 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' + ''''
        + ' AND u.name <> ' + '''' + 'guest' + ''''
        + ' AND u.name <> ' + '''' + 'dbo' + ''''
        + ' AND u.name <> ' + '''' + 'sys' + ''''
        + ' AND u.name <> ' + '''' + 'system_function_schema' + '''' + ')'

    PRINT @SQL;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

    UPDATE 
        #databases 
    SET 
        processed = 1 
    WHERE 
        database_id = @database_id;
END

SELECT 
    database_name
    , [user_name]
    , drop_command_text 
FROM 
    #orphan_users 
ORDER BY 
    [database_name]
    , [user_name];

DROP TABLE #databases;
DROP TABLE #orphan_users;

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```